# android - lowmemorykiller config property

Tags: android, low-memory

I am using Android R and confused by lowmemorykiller propertyies. From AOSP document [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/memory/lmkd/README.md;l=95?q=sys.lmk.minfree_levels&sq=&ss=android),

```
 sys.lmk.minfree_levels:    minfree:oom_adj_score pairs, delimited by comma
```

The property maybe used to config when will lowmemorykiller start take effect with MEM:SCORE pairs. I think user should set that value to adjust the lowmemorykiller sensitivity.

But from the code, looks like this property is written by lmk daemon,see code [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/memory/lmkd/lmkd.cpp;l=1407?q=sys.lmk.minfree_levels&ss=android)! property_set called here.

And I do not found the code to read this property! Does that means this is actually a read only property? then how can I config the lowmemorykiller!